# Hot to get date range filter value? (min and max)

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I use IronPython script to get some values from some filter(all are ListBoxFilter)
please see below code

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import HtmlTextArea
from System import DateTime
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataType import Date

html.As[HtmlTextArea]().HtmlContent=""

list=[]
GRF=pg.FilterPanel.TableGroups[0].GetFilter("GEOGRAPHIC_REGION").FilterReference.As[ListBoxFilter]()
for value in GRF.SelectedValues:
    if value.find(',')!=-1:
    list.append(value)
PTF=pg.FilterPanel.TableGroups[0].GetFilter("PROCEDURE_TYPE").FilterReference.As[ListBoxFilter]()
for value in PTF.SelectedValues:
    if value.find(',')!=-1:
    list.append(value)
```

if I want to get a range filter's value(min and max) and add them(min and max) to one item in the list, how to code? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get a range filter's values, use the following snippet:

```
# make sure to import the ValueRange class
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import RangeFilter, ValueRange

# get reference for and cast the filter
rf = pg.FilterPanel.TableGroups[0].GetFilter("FILTER_NAME").FilterReference.As[RangeFilter]()

# pull the current selection of the filter
current_value_range = rf.ValueRange

# returns a tuple containing the min and max filtered values
print current_value_range

# List.extend() will append each item in the tuple to the list
# you can also access them individually like current_value_range[1]
list.extend(current_value_range)
```

source on this and more info at https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.6.0/doc/api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Filters_RangeFilter.htm